# Why isn't this receiving KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN events?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash, keyboard-events

Basically I'm trying to just barely add keyboard event listeners in my program, then start building on them iteratively.  The problem is that even getting the simplest stuff in there, derived from multiple tutorials, is apparently something an issue.  I'm not too sure what I'm missing right now.  I've tried adding stuff, changing stuff, and taking stuff out.  But given the following code, I don't see any messages showing up on the screen.  Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:local="*" xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" width="480" height="600" layout="absolute" creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;

        private function onStart(pEvent:Event):void {
            vs.selectedChild = mm;
        }

        private function onNewGame(pEvent:Event):void {
            vs.selectedChild = game;
        }



        private function onCreationComplete():void {
            addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);

            addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyDown);
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyDown);
        }

        private function onKeyDown(pEvent:KeyboardEvent):void {
            Alert.show("spam");
            Alert.show(pEvent.toString());
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>
<mx:ViewStack id="vs" creationComplete="vs.selectedChild = ts">
    <local:TitleScreen id="ts" creationComplete="ts.addEventListener(TitleScreen.START, onStart);" />
    <local:MainMenu id="mm" creationComplete="mm.addEventListener(MainMenu.NEW_GAME, onNewGame);" />
    <local:Game id="game" />
</mx:ViewStack>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `stage` directly. Instead this use this code:

```
    private function onCreationComplete():void {
        systemManager.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
        systemManager.stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyDown);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, Ivan!  That did the trick.  Got a couple of questions about that though:

#1. I just now saw some documentation saying that stage cannot be accessed direclty, and that it has to be accessed from a DisplayObject.  mx:Canvas and mx:Application both inherit from that.  What's blocking me from accessing it directly from inside one of them?

#2: Is there a way to do this for different mx:Canvas-based MXML classes, complete with different event listeners, without ever putting it in the main mx:Application?

Comment: @Panzercrisis Pretty sure you can listen to the stage directly. You just need to do it after ADDED_TO_STAGE event not creation complete. The systemManager class is probably just controlling that.